# ORM vs Query Builder vs Native driver

Tags: orm, query-builder

I am really confused because I have heard a lot about ORM, I guess the best practise is to used ORM to not write SQL queries.

I tried Django ORM, Laravel ORM, Hibernate and they take much longer time to return the data.

For example: I code a script to insert a dataset using native queries and Django ORM, Django takes 4 minutes and my script take 1 minutes, more or less.

I think the response time is the more important thing when you code an api.

So, is not a better option to use the query builder?

Answer (score 1):

ORM is basically a way to introduce concepts of domain and type safety into work with databases. When you can have classes and properties with types, it's more easier to write logically structured and type safe code, also reuse existing functionality. Following these benefits, the main advantage of ORM is safety and clearness.
Also, ORM could be a way to introduce an abstraction layer, allowing semi-painless migration from one database to another as details of interaction are hidden inside ORM engine.

For small projects without many developers working on or for application with short lifetime, it's obviously not a necessity, and introduction of an ORM can be considered as a disadvantage.

Addressing your example with slow insertion of data and accusation of ORM, it can be said that probably you aren't using ORM correctly or you are using it not in the most optimized for the task way. For example, your script can use no transactions at all or probably use less restrictive isolation level whereas ORM can target safety over speed, creating a transaction on each insert or utilizing more restrictive isolation level.

Comment: I understand what you say as well as I believe there is a great dissadvantages, that is the response time and it's really important. We always try to reduce the query time.

Comment: @Knowledge with any approach people are trying to reduce query time — with ORM and with raw SQL queries. The important detail here is how much they want to reduce it. Developers would like not to have excessively unoptimized queries, however having slightly slow query is mostly acceptable, which is the case with using ORM. If we say that somewhere performance is *really* important, then query logic should be moved to database itself and stored in a procedure. Or even another database engine/kind is used — more suitable for data structure. That way the fastest possible result will be achieved.